# Is it possible to refer to the current list's length from inside the index?

Tags: python

I'd like to say something like:
[1, 2, 3, 4][len/2] where len refers to the length of this unnamed list.

Is there a way to do this in python?

Answer (score 7):

To answer your question, you cannot do this without having the list exist beforehand. However you can simply do:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> l[len(l)/2]
3
```

Comment: Now this wording is explicit and upvotable :)

Comment: Rubber-stamp comment #421: Don't use `l` as a variable name; it's too easily confused with `1`

Comment: Fair enough, just an example :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that something like that is possible out of the box. But the more pythonic way is anyway to make your idea more explizit. Why not write it like this:

```
def middle(*items):
    return items[len(items)/2]

print middle(1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

just for fun

```
def half(a):
    return len(a) / 2 

class _(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.l = list(args)
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if type(idx) == int:
            return self.l[idx]
        else:
            return self.l[idx(self.l)]

print _(1, 2, 3, 4)[half]
```

Though @Mike Lewis' answer won.